# How to properly read objects returned by philips hue

Tags: node.js, philips-hue

I am attempting to write a function in Nodejs that returns all of the devices that are in my network. I am using this code:

```
        var fs = require('fs');
        var axios = require('axios');

        var token = await fs.readFileSync("../hue_token.txt").toString();
        token = token.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        var lightResp = await axios.get(`http://192.168.1.58/api/${token}/lights`, {

        });
        var stringedResp = Object.values(lightResp);
        this.logger.info("Here is the lightResp:\n" + stringedResp);
```

But all that gets returned is:

200,OK,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Here is a small sample of what it should look like:

```
{
    "4": {
        "state": {
            "on": false,
            "bri": 254,
            "alert": "select",
            "mode": "homeautomation",
            "reachable": true
        },
        "swupdate": {
            "state": "noupdates",
            "lastinstall": "2021-08-20T16:38:24"
        },
        "type": "Dimmable light",
        "name": "Hue white lamp 1",
        "modelid": "--",
        "manufacturername": "Signify Netherlands B.V.",
        "productname": "Hue white lamp",
        "capabilities": {
            "certified": true,
            "control": {
                "mindimlevel": 5000,
                "maxlumen": 840
            },
            "streaming": {
                "renderer": false,
                "proxy": false
            }
        },
        "config": {
            "archetype": "classicbulb",
            "function": "functional",
            "direction": "omnidirectional",
            "startup": {
                "mode": "safety",
                "configured": true
            }
        },
        "uniqueid": "--",
        "swversion": "1.88.1",
        "swconfigid": "A0DE501E",
        "productid": "Philips-LWB014-1-A19DLv3"
    }
```

I am not sure what I am missing to further breakout the objects that get returned. I tried iterating through the objects with a for loop and couldn't get anything returned either.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing something simple. After the Axios call, I needed to call lightResp.data and not just lightResp.